# Source of an Image linked to a Boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml

I want to set the Source of an Image depending of the value of a Boolean.

Here is the code I have :

```
<Image DockPanel.Dock="Left">
    <Image.Source>
        [...]
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

And in [...] I can access to a Boolean (Path="Item2" - I got a Tuple) and I want to set the value of my Source depending of the value of the Boolean.
I Absolutely got no idea how to do it...
I googled it and found some tips about Setters but I didnt managed to get it work

Any help will be very appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.aspx) and [`DataTriggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx):

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ThatBool}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Path to image"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ThatBool}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Path to another image"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

*(You should be familiar with [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx))*

Comment: I was expecting something simpler but that worked perfectly :) thx !

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy: You can shave off one `DataTrigger` by extracting its setter to the `Style.Setters` collection (place it before the `Style.Triggers` tag), so it's the default value.

Answer (score 1):

You need a DataTrigger... which by the way requires a Style. Check [this link](http://www.briankeating.net/post/2009/12/04/WPF-Datatriggers.aspx).